# Hide and unhide rows based on multiple cell values (Comparison)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to do a comparison the details for a few companies (a,b,c,d), which is presented in a drop-down list in cells A1 and B1. 
I am using a VBA routine (presented further down) to hide rows when the entire row has no values but remain unhidden even with one value present

For this example 1, the routine should not hide any rows, but it hid both rows 2 and 3 but row 4 is not hidden

```
    A           B
1   Company A   Company B
2   las vegas
3               boston
4   north       north
```

How do i make sure that the VBA would not hide rows 2 and 3 in the example?

I have used the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, c As Range

    Set r = range[a2:b3]
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In r
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The VBA I used above is only useful for one column of values but not for multiple columns for comparison sake.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall, / Humpty Dumpty had a great fall. / All the king's horses and all the king's men / Couldn't put Humpty together again."  Two of us have tried to make sense of this question, and, while we may have improved it, we haven't ***fixed*** it.  Please [edit] your question and try to make it clearer.

Comment: i have made the necessary edits, hope it clarifies and thanks!

Comment: i would want the row to remain unhidden even if there is only 1 value in the row, but the current VBA will hide the row unless there is at least 2 values side by side in 2 columns as shown in row 4

Answer (score 1):

I’m a little puzzled by your problem. 
When I try to run your routine, it immediately chokes on the `Set r =` line,
because `Union()` must be given *at least* two arguments. 
But, when I change that to `Set r = [a2:b3]`,
it runs, and hides Row 2 but leaves Row 3 unhidden.

This is what I expected the routine to do.

It looks at each cell in the range `A2:B3` individually, and acts on it. 
It goes through the range from top to bottom,
and then from left to right within each row. 
(At least that is the default behavior; it might be possible to change it.) 
So this is what happens:

1. Look at cell `A2`. 
   It has a value, so we **un**hide Row 2.
2. Look at cell `B2`. 
   It doesn’t have a value, so we hide Row 2.
3. Look at cell `A3`. 
   It doesn’t have a value, so we hide Row 3.
4. Look at cell `B3`. 
   It has a value, so we **un**hide Row 3.

And so Row 2 ends up hidden and Row 3 ends up unhidden.

You need to look at the range, not as just a bunch of *cells*,
but as a bunch of rows (each of which is a bunch of cells). 
You need to have another variable,
which will take on logical (True/False) values. 
For each row, start out by setting the variable to True,
which will mean “yes, this row doesn’t have any data, as far as I know.” 
Then, for each cell in that row, if the cell has a value,
set the variable to False, which means “no, this row isn’t blank.” 
And, after you’ve looked at every cell in a row,
set the row’s `Hidden` attribute to the value of the variable.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed reply. Yes the problem arise when i want row 2 to unhide even though A2 has value and B2 has no value.

Comment: May i ask what are the variables to add on to the code to ensure that the row will not be hidden? This is because the worksheet is dynamic and i will be changing comparison between different companies and their values will change automatically too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I'm suggesting that you just add another local variable to the routine, like `r` and `c` — the name is arbitrary.

Comment: may i know how to add the extra variable?

Comment: What, exactly, do you need help with?  You know how to declare local variables — you've got two of them already.  You will learn more if you learn how to research such fundamental questions yourself.  Here are a couple of starting points: (1) This site ([SU]) has over 1200 questions tagged [vba], many of which have complete, working VBA routines with explanations.  (2) The Microsoft Office VBA Editor has pretty good built-in help.  Just click on a keyword and press the F1 key.  (Some of the help documents are actually on the web.)